# Display custom post type in desired order

Tags: wordpress

I am using following code to get all the registered custom post types. But along with that i want to display them in desired order like in the order I registered them.

```
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( 
    array(
        '_builtin' => false,
        'public'   => true
        ),
    'objects'
    );

ksort( $custom_post_types, SORT_ASC );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_type_name', 'posts_per_page' => 50 'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID), 'full' );
$url = $thumb['0'];
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">    
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="img-responsive" width="100%"/></a> 
<h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="hvr-bounce-to-top redbtn"> Read More</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I dont intend to display the posts under custom post type but itself the list of registered post type.